# What are the drawbacks of overloads?

Tags: c++, performance, overloading

Not a professional programmer but writing programs now and then, recently I heard from a guy who given a talk to us talking about some programming tips, one thing he said is that one C++ feature called operator and function overloads can hurt performance of a program.

I then did some tests, in terms of executing speed, I see no differences between some programs with function and operator overloads and these without, so what are the real drawbacks of function/operator overloads, if there are any?

Comment: Well... you have to listen to people who tell you their personal beliefs in why C++ is slow, and *that* can hurt your performance as a programmer, as well as your general patience as a human being.

Comment: Did the guy say with respect to what alternative overloads can hurt performance? It sounds like a rather odd piece of advice.

Comment: No inherent drawback... maybe something derived from missusage?

Comment: Any feature can hurt performance if misused. If he didn't say anything more specific than that, we can only guess at what he might have meant. (If I had to guess, I'd say either he misspoke or was just mindlessly repeating something he didn't understand.)

Comment: As a broad generalization, the compiler likely renders this moot, in terms of performance.

Comment: Could you be confusing overloading vs. overriding (virtual method)?  Even then, Kerrek SB speaks more truth than what you may have heard.

Comment: @franji1, no, I mean specific overloading, actually he also mentioned about virtual function hurt performance, and I actually agree with him on that one, I think he means overloading hurt a peformance of program in terms of speed and memory space etc, I tested the speed, found no diffenece, not so easy to measure the memeory space comsuption through.

Comment: @user0002128 Overloads are a little more work for the compiler/parser, but not the execution.  If you ever optimize your code for the compiler's sake, you are serving the wrong "user".

Comment: Possibly he was thinking "overloading operators makes it easier to write code, and more code takes more memory and code that does things takes time".  And to a certain extent, this is true -- once you have written a `Matrix` and `NVector` class with a pile of useful operator overloads, you can spew out a whole bunch of linear algebra code that is far less of a pain to write than doing it the old-fashioned way.  So someone writing it without operator overloading might find writing the code painful, and write less of it... and thus use less memory/execute less code!

Answer (score 3):

Function overloads have no effect on performance, whatsoever. Overload resolution is done at compile time. Naming your functions differently instead of overloading the same name is not going to matter one iota.

Operator overloads ditto, in a way. The potential trouble with operator overloads is that you might be less aware that you're using them, so you might be using expensive operations without realising it. Using a regular function instead of an overloaded operator makes this more visible. But I think it's a weak argument at best.

Answer (score 2):

Overloading won't cause any drop in execution speeds. This person may have been confusing virtual functions, which are typically implemented with a pointer indirection.

Comment: I am sure he is not talking about virtual function, actually he also mentioned virtual functions also hurt performance and I tend to agree with him on that one.

Answer (score 1):

overloading does not affect the speed of performance. Rather it reduces documentation complexity. Programmer uses the memory in better way and it is easier for him to trace the function by its name. programmer got the advantage of defining the near similar functionality with the same name.